# appropriate usage of the word "Here"

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to begin a sentence with the word *here*? If so, can anyone please give an example? In a sentence like this one, is the use of *here* grammatically correct?

> Here, first we should know the reason of…

Comment: Here, at ELU, is a place where you can pose this question.

Comment: The best I could come up with, while keeping faithful to the original sentence was: *Here, (first and foremost) we should know the reason that...*

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: Yes, of course. **Here** is an example.

Long Answer: The word "here" can be used as an adverb (google "adverbial" for hours of interesting reading), a noun, an adjective, and an interjection.

- Adverb: **Here** is the black pepper you wanted for your fish.
- Interjection: **Here**!

My experiments using "here" to begin a sentence as an adjective or noun resulted in awkward and clumsy artificial constructions. I didn't think it should count when I use the word "here" to refer to itself: **Here** refers to the word "here" in this sentence.

As for your example, I find "Here, first" to be unnatural. You haven't provided context (or a complete sentence), so I can't provide another solution. I would recommend reconstructing your paragraph(s), aiming for simplicity and clarity. You might not need the word "here" at all.

Comment: One can say something like "Here [sc. 'In this particular case'], first, it's important to keep in mind that ... and second it's also the case that ...."

Answer (score -1):

"**Here** I am, This is me...."
This is the opening phrase from a song by Bryan Adams. Of course, we can start a sentence with "here".

**Here**, take a look at some examples:

**Here** I come;

**Here** we go;

While raising a toast we usually say something like: "**Here**'s to the jobs that pay the rent!"

Answer (score -2):

If you can't trust St. John, who can you trust?

> Here is wisdom. Let him who has understanding calculate the number of the beast, for the number is that of a man; and his number is six hundred and sixty-six.

*Here* is usually a noun.  Lots of sentences begin with nouns.

Comment: Actually, it's usually an adverb or adjective, but it can function as a noun. Also, while the Bible is a very good source of wisdom for many of the most important aspects of life, I wouldn't refer to it as a source for grammar, since it was written in Greek, Hebrew and some Aramaic, and then translated into English. As anyone who has tried any translation can attest, what is grammatically correct in one language may not be in another. Translation is often a balancing act of communicating the meaning of what was said, while remaining as close to the actual words used as possible.

Comment: @Gaius619 In the case of the KJV, however, that book has done much to shape our grammar.

Comment: @Gaius619 -  the adjectival form `here` only used in colloquial or humorous speech ("This here beer is flat" or "Bob here is the expert").  And as cwallenpoole points out, we are discussing the the King James's translation, one of the glories of early modern English.  Finally, the Bible's "wisdom" about daily life is at least questionable.  It prescribes the death penalty for defiant teenagers, while awarding rapists permanent custody of their victims.  This specific book, Revelation, can most kindly be described as drug-induced.